# Element click event removed after adding new element with AJAX

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a gallery app with dynamically loaded images with `python flask` framework and vanilla `JS`. Also, I made a full image viewer, so when you click on an image, it opens in a larger scale.

When I open the page for the first time, all works fine. But when load new images, the `event`, that triggers full viewer is removed on all images in gallery.

What's the reason?

Here is code.

#### Python. Sending list of images url:

```
@app.route('/loadmore', methods=['GET'])
def load_more():
    return jsonify(get_images(5))
```

#### JS. XMLHttpRequest to get images url's:

```
function loadMore() {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      addImages(xhr.responseText);
    }
  };

  xhr.open("GET", "/loadmore", true);
  xhr.send();
}
```

#### JS. Adding new images to HTML:

```
function addImages(paths) {
  let images = document.getElementById("images");
  paths = JSON.parse(paths);
  paths.forEach((path) => {
    images.innerHTML += `<img class="grid-image" src="static/images/${path}">`;
  });
}
```

#### Before loading new images

[image: Before loading new images]

#### After loading new images

[image: After loading new images]

Comment: do you try to add `onclick = "full_image_viewer_fn()"` to `img` tag ,

Comment: `<img onclick="full_image_viewer_fn()" class="grid-image" src="static/images/${path}">`

Comment: @AhmadMRF, No I didn't. Although it should work, I want to add listener with JS code, not hard-code it.

Comment: Using innerHTML recreates the entire content of your  div, everything that was there before is lost, however you added the events before you're going to have to do it again after you loadMore images.

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions: add event listener every time, when load new images.

#### add new images to HTML

```
function addImages(paths) {
  let images_grid = document.getElementById("images");
  paths = JSON.parse(paths);
  paths.forEach((path) => {
    images_grid.innerHTML += `<img class="grid-image" src="static/images/${path}">`;
  });

  addClickEvent();
}
```

#### add event listener

```
function addClickEvent() {
  const images = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-image");
  images.forEach((el) => {
    el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      full_viewer.children[0].setAttribute("src", e.target.getAttribute("src"));
      full_viewer.classList.toggle("hidden");
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add `event` on every `img` tag .

```js
function full_image_viewer(){}

function addImages(paths) {
  let images = document.getElementById("images");
  paths = JSON.parse(paths);
  paths.forEach((path) => {
  const img = document.createElement('img')
  img.className = 'grid-image';
  img.src = `static/images/${path}`;
  img.addEventListener('click',full_image_viewer )
  images.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend',img)
  });
}
```